# How to add pop-up to map marker on HERE Maps (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, maps, here-api

The base code comes with a Metadata pop-up but I can't figure out how to transform it to display the data from an API call in the pop-up, relevant to the individual map marker, which are all placed via a different API call already.

The Map Marker API call contains an ID in the Json feedback, I need to take that ID and call a separate API with that in the URL of the call, to then display within the pop-up.

I can fetch the data fine via a `call` and display as list - I am just stuggling to integrate it into a pop-up for its relevant marker

The markers place fine on the map via the API call, but the pop-up displays stock Metadata via a `string` in the code

I can find little documentation on the subject of placing API data in a HERE Map pop-up, built in Flutter for mobile.

This code adds the marker to the map, Metadata function at the bottom

```
Future<void> _addPOIMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, int drawOrder) async {


    if (_poiMapImage == null) {
      Uint8List imagePixelData = await _loadFileAsUint8List('assets/poi.png');
      _poiMapImage = MapImage.withPixelDataAndImageFormat(imagePixelData, ImageFormat.png);
    }

    Anchor2D anchor2D = Anchor2D.withHorizontalAndVertical(0.5, 1);

    MapMarker mapMarker = MapMarker.withAnchor(geoCoordinates, _poiMapImage, anchor2D);
    mapMarker.drawOrder = drawOrder;

    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.setString("key_poi", "T");
    mapMarker.metadata = metadata;

    _hereMapController.mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker);
    _mapMarkerList.add(mapMarker);

  }
```

```
Future<void> _addCircleMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, int drawOrder) async {
   
    if (_circleMapImage == null) {
      Uint8List imagePixelData = await _loadFileAsUint8List('assets/circle.png');
      _circleMapImage = MapImage.withPixelDataAndImageFormat(imagePixelData, ImageFormat.png);
    }

    MapMarker mapMarker = MapMarker(geoCoordinates, _circleMapImage);
    mapMarker.drawOrder = drawOrder;

    _hereMapController.mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker);
    _mapMarkerList.add(mapMarker);
  }
```

```
Future<Uint8List> _loadFileAsUint8List(String assetPathToFile) async {

    ByteData fileData = await rootBundle.load(assetPathToFile);
    return Uint8List.view(fileData.buffer);
  }

  void _setTapGestureHandler() {
    _hereMapController.gestures.tapListener = TapListener.fromLambdas(lambda_onTap: (Point2D touchPoint) {
      _pickMapMarker(touchPoint);
    });
  }

  void _pickMapMarker(Point2D touchPoint) {
    double radiusInPixel = 2;
    _hereMapController.pickMapItems(touchPoint, radiusInPixel, (pickMapItemsResult) {
     
      List<MapMarker> mapMarkerList = pickMapItemsResult.markers;
      if (mapMarkerList.length == 0) {
        print("No map markers found.");
        return;
      }

      MapMarker topmostMapMarker = mapMarkerList.first;
      Metadata metadata = topmostMapMarker.metadata;
      if (metadata != null) {
        String message = metadata.getString("key_poi") ?? "No message found.";
        _showDialog("ND", message);
        return;
      }

      _showDialog("ND", "No metadata attached.");
    });
  }
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display varying content on a specific location, you may consider to use [MapViewPins](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.7.6.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html#add-map-view-pins).

Just create any Flutter Widget with the content you would like to see:

```
Widget _createWidget(String label, Color backgroundColor) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: backgroundColor,
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    child: Text(
      label,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then you can use the HERE SDK with one line of code to show that widget on a location:

```
_hereMapController.pinWidget(
    _createWidget("My label for this location...", Color.fromARGB(150, 0, 194, 138)), GeoCoordinates(52.5309, 13.3946));
```

In opposition, `MapMarker` objects are composed out of static image assets, so they are not made to show varying content. However, the `MapMarker` class also supports SVG assets. You can update the SVG asset on the fly, set it to an existing `MapMarker` instance and the content will be updated. This only requires you to deal with the XML-based SVG format. A benefit may be that this may have a better performance over native Flutter widgets, ... but this depends on how complex your widgets are and how many widgets you need to display at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The ```Map Marker``` objects are placed according to the response of an API call, so are not guaranteed to be reoccurring. The Markers placed will then have another call made to place the pop-up info, specific to the Map Markers credentials. Does the ```map marker``` have the functionality to accommodate a call to populate the info bubble? Thanks again

Comment: This sounds like pure app logic, so the answer is yes. The MapMarker or ViewPin classes can be tapped, for example. Then you can initiate a call and show another bubble, if you want. Or you can show a popup (composed from a widget) based on any other custom logic you may have.